# Get page URL for scheduled publishing

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-pageurl

My editors want to know the end page url for publishing in social media.
Is there any way to get the page URL as when it will be published before actually publishing it (scheduled publishing)?

Answer (score 0):

`slug_url` should give you what you need:
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/writing_templates.html?highlight=slugurl#slugurl-tag

Note that `slugurl` might provide a relative link, so if it does, then you would have to prepend the domain name to the relative url in order to create the final url for the user. See the `test_slugurl_tag()` routine [in the tests](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/716bf92c2dc2da2aca5e8f5aa6768b5b087cd4b0/wagtail/core/tests/tests.py) for an example of how to use `slugurl` in Python code.

Note also that if the location of the page in the page tree is changed or the slug (as defined in the `Promote` tab) is changed, then the url that you retrieved with `slugurl` prior to any such change will no longer be valid.  However, if you are using Wagtail 2.16+, then this [problem can be handled automatically](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/releases/2.16.html#automatic-redirect-creation) if you use the `wagtail.contrib.redirects` app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's actually a bit more complicated I'll post a complete solution soon

Answer (score 0):

Here a code snippet that takes in account when the slug changes or the page is moved in the tree (you will need to subclass the Page model somehow and add a new field `published_url`):

```
    def save_revision(self, user=None, submitted_for_moderation=False, approved_go_live_at=None, changed=True,
                  log_action=False, previous_revision=None, clean=True):
    old_record = Page.objects.get(id=self.id)
    if old_record.slug != self.slug:
        kwargs = {'update_fields': ['slug']}
        Page.save(self, kwargs)
    self.published_url = self.get_full_url()
    return Page.save_revision(self, user, submitted_for_moderation, approved_go_live_at, changed,
                              log_action, previous_revision, clean)
```